# Chrome seems to have a handle on shortcut keys even when its not running

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ, the key combo CTRL + SHIFT + N is supposed to open the 'Go to file' dialog. Pushing these keys instead opens up a new incognito window in Chrome.

Even when Chrome is not running, and no matter which program I am currently in, CTRL + SHIFT + N always opens a new incognito Chrome window.

Anyone have any idea what's happening here? I'm running the Chrome beta channel (current version 16.0.912.63 beta-m) on Windows 7.

Comment: Does the same behavior occur with actual Chrome releases? Is there a Chrome-related helper process in the process list of *Task Manager*?

Comment: @sim Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you download the free version of Hotkey Commander from http://hkcmdr.anymania.com you should be able to see what program is handling this key.

If you can't stop the program that registers it, then the non-free version should allow you to disable or change the hotkey, but I have not actually tested that feature.

I'm using Chrome version 17.0.963.0 dev-m in Windows7 and Ctrl+Shift+N is not registered as a hotkey and hence just works inside Chrome.

Comment: No, do not do that. See my comment at https://superuser.com/questions/764598/windows-global-shortcut-hijacked-by-opera/765148#comment2361395_765148  as the Hotkey commander is indeed malware and will/may mess up your Windows 10 host.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, at least for me, was a short-key set in ClipX for navigate. I have no idea how that was set. Just check ClipX configuration -> Hotkeys and set None on navigate. Hope t