# Windows global shortcut hijacked by Opera

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, opera

I have Chrome 37 installed as my main browser. Recently I needed to test a design in a new, Chromium based Opera version 21.0.1432.67.

This later one hijacked my global shortcuts somehow, so if I press Ctrl+Shift+N to start a new session for testing, even if Chrome is running, and it is the active window, the shortcut starts a new Opera tab - even if the program is not running.

It is highly annoying. Even if I uninstall Opera, I'm unable to use the aforementioned shortcut, because it will not work at all.

Any hints on how to restore the original shortcut?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Chrome?

Comment: search the registry for the executable name

Comment: yes, i did a complete uninstall and reinstall of Chrome while having Opera installed, but no luck.

Comment: @AthomSfere i did a search, but no relevant matches in the registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...with the help of [Hotkey commander 2.1](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) I figured out that Ctrl+Shift+N was handled globally by ClipX (which is by the way a nice app for managing the clipboard) and it started Opera as a default browser for such an action. By disabling ClipX's global shortcuts everything is back on track.

Comment: Warning! Hotkey commander from their website is malware. I installed it on a Windows 10 laptop and the act of installing it caused windows to be popped up, and started playing a voice saying "Your windows shell can be improved ..." at which time I quickly cold booted, used System Restore, and ran my anti-virus scan.    Don't be an idiot like I was.