# Windows global shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+n hijacked by Microsoft Outlook

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, global

Running Windows 10:

Similar to [Windows global shortcut hijacked by Opera](https://superuser.com/questions/764598/windows-global-shortcut-hijacked-by-opera) but the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> keybinding is globally bound to open up, or activate and then raise, the Microsoft Outlook window.  This conflicts with the Google Chrome keybinding for opening up an incognito window:

[image: IMG:]

I can override it using a [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script using conditional logic that is active *only* when Google Chrome window is active, allowing the binding to do whatever it is predefined to do in other windows:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; Map CTRL+SHIFT+n to activate the Google Chrome window and pass it on, instead of allowing Windows to open up a new instance of Outlook:
; See also https://superuser.com/q/1552465/106977 
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
$^+n::
Send, !f{Enter}i
return
```

And I *might* be able to code that script to raise the Google Chrome Window and pass along the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> keybinding, but that smacks of overkill: Is the installation of Outlook commandeering that keybinding, or is some other application doing it?

How do I do that? Or is it really the case that Windows is doing this, and also *not* documenting it properly since that keybinding is not in the documentation at [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts).

**Update on 2020-05-18 06:57:00**: The following process, when killed, allows the CTRL+SHIFT+n keybinding to be handled properly by the Google Chrome process (which now opens up an incognito window as expected).  But it has disastrous consequences: The desktop disappears! :

explorer.exe    9760    DLL C:\Users\thatuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\20.052.0311.0011\amd64\FileSyncShell64.dll

**Update on 2020-05-18 07:06:39**: I searched for OneDrive shortcuts (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=onedrive+%22ctrl%2Bshift%2Bn%22&ia=web) and found conflicting information for various versions of OneDrive, none of which state that CTRL+SHIFT+n should open up a new/pre-existent instance of Outlook:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-onenote-44b8b3f4-c274-4bcc-a089-e80fdcc87950?ocmsassetID=HA010386947&CorrelationId=132aca36-4c6c-43b4-a366-7a9cc350fc2f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneDrive-app-for-Windows-10-fcdb66e5-fde6-4654-bbae-21a5e0d88a0b
https://www.customguide.com/cheat-sheet/onedrive-for-business-quick-reference.pdf

**Update on 2020-05-18 07:23:34**: I uninstalled OneDrive, and that made the FileSyncShell64.dll no longer appear. I rebooted and retested, and CTRL+SHIFT+n still invokes Outlook.  Now, given that I killed explorer.exe earlier, killing that did fix the problem, but that masked the real culprit which is yet to be found (explorer.exe is, as I recall, critical for all of Windows to function). Thus, killing off explorer.exe is not the solution. I also believe that uninstalling Outlook is a non-option because I need Outlook, I just don’t want this global hijacking of the CTRL+SHIFT+n shortcut.

Comment: I updated the question to include the hackaround AutoHotkey script that works. However, that is not the answer to what I'm looking for, which is to figure out what is hijacking the  keybinding to cause it to be different from its default.  And see also [my comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1552465/windows-global-shortcut-ctrlshiftn-hijacked-by-microsoft-outlook#comment2361396_1552467) for a non-solution.

Comment: If I remember correctly the OneNote system-tray launcher grabs Ctrl-Shift-N for "new Note". That would look as a system-wide high-jack of the key-binding.

Comment: @Tonny You are on to something, or so I thought, and worked through disabling OneNote startup "things" using https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns (which did not implicate OneNote). See https://superuser.com/questions/1552465/windows-global-shortcut-ctrlshiftn-hijacked-by-microsoft-outlook#comment2362132_1552467 where I found that some DLL inside OneDrive might to be the culprit. And see my **Update on 2020-05-18 06:57:00** in my OP.

Comment: Added **Update on 2020-05-18 07:06:39** to search for any relationship between OneDrive and Outlook and came up empty.

Comment: Added **Update on 2020-05-18 07:23:34** for further failed experiments with uninstalling OneDrive.

Comment: My bad. OneNote uses Windows-N and Windows-Shift-N. On my Windows 10 machine however Ctrl-Shift-N is New Folder on the desktop/Explorer (if nothing else has focus). If another appliation has focus it is tied to whatever that application binds it to. This matches with the behavior Miroslav  mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that MS Outlook uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> as a global shortcut. I see it [documented](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd) as *Create a note* local command and it has no global action on my computer, but the shortcut is appropriately interpreted by any focused application, for example by browsers.

Just check your 3rd-party apps for potential handling of the shortcut.
Start exiting/killing your apps and processes until the behavior stops. This will point you to potential evil-doer.

Help: You can stop the apps in the following way.

1. Exit all open standard applications.
2. Exit all apps which have their icon in notification area (next to the clock) and can be exited.
3. Using [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) from Microsoft list all your running processes, display column **Company Name** (menu **View** > **Select Columns...**) and sort the list by that column.
4. Now you can safely skip all Microsoft processes or processes from known company names. Focus on the rest. Properties window of each process shows field **Path** showing you where the EXE is located. This may also say a lot. If in doubt, try right-clicking the process and select **Check VirusTotal** (it should return 0 positives although some false flags may appear) and then maybe kill it.

---

One forgotten feature: check **Properties** window of all your shortcuts on Desktop and in Start menu, which are potentially opening Outlook. On **Shortcut** tab in their **Properties** window, they have **Shortcut Key** field. Make sure you did not fill <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> there in some shortcut!

Comment: I confirmed with my system administrators that CTRL+SHIFT+n being mapped to invoking and/or re-activating Outlook is not normal.  There apparently is no way to find out what is mapping that keybinding to Outlook (at least, the answer at https://superuser.com/a/765148/106977 is actually pointing to malware, as I have discovered the hard way).

Comment: The problem of exiting/killing apps until the behavior stops is presuming there are apps that can be killed in that manner. How can a non-expert know which is safe to kill?

Comment: See my OP: I added **Update on 2020-05-18 06:57:00**: So it turns out that "Now you can safely skip all Microsoft processes..." is not true. But killing explorer.exe is also not a solution of course. But it gives a hint that the thing that installed that DLL is/might-be the culprit. OneDrive?

Comment: Given what I found in my own answer, as stated from the Microsoft site, Outlook does indeed install that shortcut.  My comment on the Microsoft site thread was a complaint of "I was completely stumped by why Microsoft chose to not document this global shortcut anywhere that I could see."  Thus, I consider this a documentation defect in the Microsoft products for Microsoft Outlook 2013. I hope that this defect is addressed when my company migrates to a more recent version of Outlook.

Comment: @bgoodr – Are you really sure that the shortcut was placed there by the Office installation? I would say no, because I never had the same issue when using Office 2013. **Ctrl+Shift+N always worked flawlessly along with Office 2013** as I know from SnagIt screen capture tool, where I used to use it for built-in functionality similarly as you do in Chrome. There was no hijacking.

Comment: No I am not. So, good point!  If there was a log somewhere that could identify what program added it, or even the forgetful user, that would settle it.  You know, if the user did it and forgot, then that would account for why Outlook's online docs don't have any record of it.

Comment: @bgoodr – I would also say the same. There was a period also in my user life when I was setting these shortcuts, too (but via much less colliding **Ctrl+Alt+Shift**+letter). Later I switched to the AutoHotKey. I appreciate your fairness to admit this most likely reason. Also I appreciate your rarely-seen sportsmanship in marking the answer. And third, I appreciate level of detail found in your own helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The last paragraph of [miroxlav's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1552467/106977) **is** the answer.  The previous part was also very instrumental in eliminating other possible causes of this problem.  I did not notice that last paragraph at the point that I wrote this answer. This answer, however, had a lot of detail that shows how to get to that shortcut definition, so I'm leaving this answer in, and marking [miroxlav's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1552467/106977) as "the" answer.

---

I cross-posted to https://answers.microsoft.com, which provided the answer:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/ctrlshiftn-is-opening-microsoft-outlook-2013/c1be666a-dc50-4097-b828-449f7e75fa4d?messageId=00ad1b54-848b-4067-a60b-bb7735cfb810&tm=1590154202614

I rewrote their answer below, to avoid eventual link-rot, add a method to find the Outlook Properties dialog box for the case whereby you don't have a taskbar or desktop shortcut, and to add context for Google Chrome's handling of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> shortcut.   Also, the section there starting at:

> In order to enable this combination for Google Chrome,...

is not correct in this case (Google Chrome already handles the shortcut by default, and by changing it globally might obviate launching incognito windows), so that section is not included here:

---

Check for the case where the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> shortcut is enabled in Properties of the Outlook launch shortcut icon, as follows:

1. Right mouse click on the **Outlook shortcut icon** in the **Taskbar** or on the **Desktop** until you see the **Outlook** menu entry. You will see something like this: [image]

   1. If you don't have Outlook pinned to the **Taskbar** or a Outlook **Desktop** shortcut, you can still navigate to the Properties menu through the Start menu: [image]
2. Right mouse click on the **Outlook** menu entry, and select **Properties**. You will see something like this:[image]
3. If you see CTRL + Shift + N there, then that is the global shortcut that is opening up Outlook when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is pressed, which results in preventing *all other* applications (such as Google Chrome in this case) from seeing and processing it for their purposes (e.g., for opening up an incognito window).
4. Under **Shortcut tab**, you will see the “**Shortcut key**” field.
5. Click inside the “**Shortcut key**” field, and press **Backspace**. The option should show “**None**”.
6. Click on **OK**.
7. This should remove the key combination to launch Outlook.
8. You should *not* have to logout/login, nor have to reboot for this change to take effect.

Now, test this out by opening up a Google Chrome window (one that is already executing is fine), and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. It should now open up the incognito window.

Comment: I read your entire today's answer and I see it reproduces the solution I wrote you 6 days ago. I kindly ask for the feedback whether the solution was clear enough or not.

Comment: @miroxlav I do not understand the phrase "it reproduces the solution".  I did reference your answer in my answer, and stated that it was invaluable because of the possibilities that it eliminated. So your answer was helpful and was well written.  Your answer was not a solution, but was instrumental in helping me find the solution, because it led me to look for answers on the Microsoft site.

Comment: Okay, in the last paragraph of my answer, there was exact solution to find a shortcut icon on the Desktop or in the Start menu and remove the Shortcut key from it. You repeated that in details in your answer later, what is possibly OK. I am just asking, what was unclear when I wrote the same in my answer so I can improve that paragraph. Thank you.

Comment: @miroxlav I did not see that latter answer upon first read. Either I just plain didn't read that far down and missed it, or it was subsequently edited and then added at the end. I don't know. Let's call it my fault for now. I've marked your answer as "the" answer. Thank you for sticking with it!